# How to add a foreign key that is a reserved word in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to alter a table in oracle SQL to add a foreign key to it which name is a reserved word ("Date" to be specific).
I tried using double quotations, single quotations, no quotations, and squared brackets but nothing seems to work.

My code goes as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE GAME ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Date") REFERENCES SCHEDULE("Date");
```

The error it shows with double quotations is: `ORA-00904: "Date": invalid identifier`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would say STOP RIGHT THERE ..  You're though process is flawed if you are wanting to circumvent **reserved** terms.  The question you should be asking is why would you want to do that?  And is there ANY other name you could give your key?  Not only for the integrity of your software, but for the sanity of anyone else who has to follow your code behind you.

Comment: use `dt` or a similar term; for column names, constraints, and everything else that you might create. It's generally bad practice to use reserved words for objects.

Comment: It is already too late to change column names, and it is not my code initially to alter it in such a way.

Comment: *"It is already too late to change column names"*  It's only too late if you decide not to confront the code developer and say "These are reserved terms, you can't use these" ..

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to:

1. Name columns after reserved words.
2. Have to always use quoted identifiers (and the correct case) for those columns.
3. Only have unique dates in your schedule table.

However, if you really do then assuming you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schedule ("Date" DATE);
CREATE TABLE game ("Date" DATE);
```

Then you can create a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `schedule` table which will be used as the "target" of the referential constraint.

```sql
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE ADD CONSTRAINT schedule__date__u UNIQUE ("Date");
```

Then create the foreign key constraint on the `game` table:

```
ALTER TABLE GAME ADD CONSTRAINT game__date__fk FOREIGN KEY ("Date") REFERENCES SCHEDULE("Date");
```

Or, if you want the system name to name the constraint then your code works:

```sql
ALTER TABLE GAME ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Date") REFERENCES SCHEDULE("Date");
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9832199ac59b6d2e4bd38644c3b8f69)*